# How to save Outlook e-mail body text to Excel

Tags: python, excel, outlook

I am new to Python and am seeking for some assistance in one of my small project trying to automate some task at work.

On a daily basis, I receive an e-mail with data in it's message body. I will do a CTRL+A, CTRL+C for the e-mail message body then CTRL+A, CTRL+V in an Excel xlsv file.

I have tried the below code and am successful in (i) searching for that specific e-mail, (ii) displaying the e-mail message body in output. However, I encountered problem saving the output into excel. When I try the code below, I only managed to save the output into one single cell.

How can I save the output such that it is shown with proper formatting etc.?

Example of Outlook E-mail Message

```
Report Date 10 Dec 2019
Transaction Date 9 Dec 2019
    *-   Blank Row  -*
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column 6
Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 4 *blank* Data 6
```

I will need the output to be saved in this format for Excel xlsv

```
[Report Date]      [10 Dec 2019]
[Transaction Date] [9 Dec 2019]
- Blank row in Excel xlsv -
[Column 1][Column 2][Column 3][Column 4][Column 5]   [Column 6]
[Data 1]  [Data 2]  [Data 3]  [Date 4]  [blank cell] [Data 6]
```

```
import datetime
import win32com.client
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

today = datetime.date.today()
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
finalfolder = outlook.getDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Final Folder")

def savemessage(subject):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject.find(subject) >= 0 and message.Unread and message.Senton.date() == today or \
        message.Subject.find(subject) >= 0 and message.Senton.date() == today:
            body_content = message.body
            print(body_content)
            wb = load_workbook("EXCEL XLSX")
            sheets = wb.sheetnames
            Sheet1 = wb[sheets[0]]
            Sheet1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = body_content
            wb.save("EXCEL XLSX")
            if message.Subject.find(subject) >= 0 and message.Unread and message.Senton.date() == today:
                message.Unread = False
                message.move(finalfolder)
            elif message.Subject.find(subject) >= 0 and message.Senton.date() == today:
                message.move(finalfolder)
                break

savemessage("SPECIFIC E-MAIL SUBJECT")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're experiencing is coming from `Sheet1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = body_content`. Could you try looping through instead?

Additionally, you could try just csv. When I write to csv it goes into an Excel file and it's a much nicer format than whenever I've worked with openpxyl.

For example:

```
import csv
     strFile = r'C:\users\username\Desktop\csvfilename.csv'
        f = open(strFile, "w")
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
        try: 
            if os.path.isfile(strFile):
                os.remove(strFile)
        except PermissionError:
            pass
        head = ['[Report Date]', '[10 Dec 2019]']
        csvwriter.writerow(head)
        for row in messages():
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you paste everything in one cell. Of course everything is there because a cell in Excel can interpret new lines (by pressing ALT + ENTER you can make a new line in a excel cell)

One method as described you can use csv which I would do as well. If you really want to use excel here a working example how to do it:

```
msg = "Report Date 10 Dec 2019 \r\n" +\
        "Transaction Date 9 Dec 2019 \r\n"+ \
        "*-   Blank Row  -* \r\n" +\
        "Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 \r\n"+\
        "Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 *blank* Data6 \r\n"

filename = "excel.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
Sheet1 = wb[sheets[0]]
for line_index, line in enumerate(msg.split("\r\n")):
    if line_index == 0:
        Sheet1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Report Date"
        Sheet1.cell(row=1, column=2).value = " ".join(line.split(" ")[2:])
    elif line_index == 1:
        Sheet1.cell(row=2, column=1).value = "Transaction Date"
        Sheet1.cell(row=2, column=2).value = " ".join(line.split(" ")[2:])
    elif line.lstrip().startswith("*"):
        continue
    else:
        for cell_index, cell in enumerate(line.split(" ")):
            if cell.startswith("*"):
                cell=""
            Sheet1.cell(row=line_index+1,column=cell_index+1).value = cell
wb.save(filename)
```

This work with the example you provided. As you can see you have to define splitting parameter. I choose `\r\n` for a new line (as standard in Windows which I assume you are using otherwise you have to change it) and as the cell separator I use blank. If you are using something else (for example tabulator `\t` change it accordingly). Be careful what you choose, since it is not visible how your data look like I go with my assumptions, because you need some sort of separator.

As well I assume if a starts with a * (or a cell) it is always a blank row/cell (that is why the continue is here for to skip a line without doing anything.

I also assume that the header never change (line_index=0 and line_index=1) except for the date.

I hope this help you.